# Java finding start and end of each sub-sequence in an int array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this array containing some sequence of numbers like below, which is a sequence of the number of pixels in `y` axis (horizontal projection histogram):

```
[ 0 0 3 13 16 16 18 19 19 18 14 10 8 0 0 0 0 0 7 13 15 16 19 20 18 17 14 9 0 0 0 0 ]
      ^                            ^
    start                         end
```

How can I find the starting index and the ending index of each sub-sequence in this array?
What I expect in this example it would be something like this: *first sub-sequence:* `startIndex = 2, endIndex = 12` and the *second sub-sequence:* `startIndex = 18, endIndex = 27`.

what I have came up with:

```
for(int i =0; i<pixels.length; i++){
        System.out.println(pixels[i]);
        if(pixels[i] != 0) {
            start = i;
            System.out.println("start= " + start );
        } else if(pixels[i] == 0){
            end = i;
            System.out.println("end= " + end);
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little?

Comment: 1) You've described a problem and how you can't do it, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question? 2) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: And ..where is the '?' in that lot of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating trough your array, you don't keep track if you already started your sequence.

With this small change it should work

```
int start=-1;
for(int i =0; i<pixels.length; i++){
        System.out.println(pixels[i]);
        if(pixels[i] != 0 && start == -1) {
            start = i;
            System.out.println("start= " + start );
        } else if(pixels[i] == 0 && start != -1;){
            end = i;
            start = -1;
            System.out.println("end= " + end);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to quite give you the answer so here's some logic that might help

- `while` you are encountering 0s, you can skip them
- your first non zero becomes the start
- `while` you are encountering non zeros, continue along
- when you encounter a zero, your end is the index - 1.  Then go to step 1

You want to also make sure to deal with zero length sequences and sequence termination.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
start = -1;
for(int i =0; i<pixels.length; i++){
            System.out.println(pixels[i]);
            if(pixels[i] != 0 && start == -1) {
                start = i;
                System.out.println("start= " + start );
            } else if(pixels[i] == 0 && start != -1){
                end = i;
                start = -1;
                System.out.println("end= " + end);
            }
        }
```